# Failed to parse XML

Tags: apex, xml, xmlparsing

I've getting a problem when trying to parse an XML.
The logs says:

> System.XmlException: Failed to parse XML due to: markup not allowed
> inside attribute value - illegal < (position: START_TAG seen
> ...la.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado="AGENCIA : BOGOTA
> (2).\n<... @3:2)

The code that thows that exception is the following:

```
    strReturn = strReturn.unescapeHtml4().unescapeXml();
    
    objDocument = null;
    objDocument = new DOM.Document();
    
    
    try{
              strReturn = strReturn.replace('&', '&amp;');
              objDocument.load(strReturn); //The problem occurs here
    
    
    
              bodyNode = objDocument.getRootElement();
    
    
              DOM.XmlNode datosBasicosNode = bodyNode.getChildElement('DatosBasicos', null);
              //------------
    }catch(Exception objException){
              System.debug(' ERROR ===> '+objException.getMessage());
    }
```

`strReturn` is the XML that I try to parse to get the 'DatosBasicos'.
I'm try to understand what's going on.

What should I do to fix the problem?

The squeleton of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DatosBasicos ciudad="" esConfecamaras=""><DatosBasicos>
<IdClase> </IdClase>
<NumId> </NumId>
<NombreCliente> </NombreCliente>
<OrganizacionJuridica> </OrganizacionJuridica>
<CategoriaEmpresa> </CategoriaEmpresa>
<NroMatricula> </NroMatricula> <FecMatricula>
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
</TxtCertificado></DatosConstitucion><DatosError><CodRetorno>0</CodRetorno></DatosError></DatosBasicos>
```

Comment: The error here is describing a problem with the XML rather than the code you're using to process it. Please [edit] your question to provide the XML you're trying to parse.

Comment: There's a hint from the error that the attribute TxtCertificado has a value that includes "<". This should have previously been encoded to "&lt;" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is malformed. These lines are suspect:

```
<DatosBasicos ciudad="" esConfecamaras=""><DatosBasicos>
```

Is this really supposed to be a DatosBasicos with a nested DatosBasicos?

```
<NroMatricula> </NroMatricula> <FecMatricula>
```

This includes an open tag for FecMatricula, but there's no closing tag later in the document.

```
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
<paralela.ccbdw.dbo.ft_certificas TxtCertificado=""
```

The self-close tag markup is missing (the "/>" is missing at the end of each line).

```
</TxtCertificado>...
```

There's no open tag to match this closing tag. Other open and close tags on this line are also unbalanced.

Whatever is generating this XML is doing a really bad job.

Comment: To be pedantic, self-closing means `<tag />`, otherwise it's just a normal closing tag (`</tag>`).

Comment: @sfdcfox but that is what I said... missing "/>"...

Comment: Oh. Looks like I misread/confused myself. Carry on. 